# How to create hyperlink of local file in excel using Java

Tags: java, excel, hyperlink

I would like to insert a local file which was placed in my laptop in to Excel by creating a hyperlink using java.
I have wrote the following code and the code was successfully executed with no errors, but when am trying to open the excel to see the hyperlink, only text was seen but no hyperlink was created on mouse hovering.

```
package practise;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.Hyperlink;
import org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.HyperlinkType;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFHyperlink;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class HyperLink {
    public static void addLink() throws IOException {
        // Create a Workbook
        XSSFWorkbook myWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        // Create a Spread Sheet
        XSSFSheet newSpreadsheet = myWorkbook.createSheet("Custom Links");
        XSSFCell cell;

        // Create Helpers
        CreationHelper helper = myWorkbook.getCreationHelper();
        XSSFCellStyle linkStyle = myWorkbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont linkFont = myWorkbook.createFont();

        // Setting the Link Style
        linkFont.setUnderline(XSSFFont.U_SINGLE);
        linkFont.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
        linkStyle.setFont(linkFont);

        // Adding a Link
        cell = newSpreadsheet.createRow(1).createCell((short) 2);
        cell.setCellValue("Link");
        XSSFHyperlink link = (XSSFHyperlink) helper.createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.FILE);
        String url = "file:///C:%5CUsers%5CTest%5Ceclipse-workspace%5CTest%5COTest.mp3";
        url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        System.out.println("URL is : " + url);
        link.setAddress(url);
        cell.setHyperlink((XSSFHyperlink) link);
        cell.setCellStyle(linkStyle);

        // Writing the File
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(ck
                new File("./Test.xls"));

        // Writing the content
        myWorkbook.write(output);
        output.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        addLink();
    }
}
```

Comment: Modern Windows systems are able interpreting the slash as well as the back-slash in file paths. So no need to over complicating things. Please try: `String url = "file:///C:/Users/Test/eclipse-workspace/Test/OTest.mp3";`. If that not works please tell used versions of Excel and Apache POI.

Comment: Resolved on my own by passing the URL to URLEncoder String url = "file:///" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Test.mp3";
                                url = URLEncoder.encode(url);